# Homestead - This site refused to connect

Tags: laravel

I installed Virtual Box and Vagrant. I also set up my Homestead, but when I try to run my domain it doesn't load and shows the error - this site refused to connect. Here's my homestead.yaml file :

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Projects/MVC
      to: /home/vagrant/MVC

sites:
    - map: infoStudio.test
      to: /home/vagrant/MVC/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Answer (score 0):

yaml files require specific new lines and indentations.

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/resources/Homestead.yaml).

For more information, take a look at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).

The correct syntax for your file would be:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    -   ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    -   map: C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Projects/MVC
        to: /home/vagrant/MVC

sites:
    -   map: infoStudio.test
    -   to: /home/vagrant/MVC/public

databases:
    -   homestead
```

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please mark this answer as the solution to your problem. Otherwise let us know if you still have problems.